# Can't install mysql 5.1 on a windows machine because the last install left artifacts

Tags: mysql, windows-7

After uninstalling mysql 5.1 (64 bit version) I cannot install the win32 version! Apparently the devs felt it neccasery to leave helpful artifacts behind? I have rebooted my machine but no effect..

Running this:

```
C:\Users\User1>net start mysql
The MySQL service is starting.
The MySQL service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

And ran this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>mysqld --console
100213 10:52:58 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 10485760 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 25165824 bytes!
100213 10:52:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
100213 10:52:59 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

100213 10:52:59 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported table type: INNODB
100213 10:52:59 [ERROR] Aborting

100213 10:52:59 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

**Update**: For some reason it looks like it is installing the 32bit DB into the old 64bit directoy.... will look into this... (the bin directory is going into the 32 bit program files directory).

Comment: Please provide more context (such as error messages). This makes it a lot easier for us to answer your questions.

Comment: Yah beat me to it brah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size" is a clue that your config file (my.cnf) and the contents of the data directory don't match anymore. I'd uninstall, look for whatever directory ib_logfile0 is in, move the contents of that directory somewhere else, and reinstall. On the other hand, if you want to keep the databases from the 64-bit instance, you might be able to just rename the InnoDB log files, and MySQL will recreate them when it starts.

The installer probably doesn't delete the data directory during an uninstall because someone might not expect their databases to get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Unfortunately I tried so many things that I can't give you the exact "walk through". 
Anyway, try this:

1. Uninstall MySQL from the Control Panel
2. check in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini` (or `C:\Program Files (86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini`) for the data files location. This is what i had:

   ```
   datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"
   ```
3. delete the folder `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/`. Other option is C:\MySQL InnoDB Datafiles or something like that.
4. Install MySQL but do not run the configuration. Stop after the software is installed
5. Go to C`:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\` and rigth-click on  `MySQLInstanceConfig.exe`. Select "Run as Administrator"
6. Leave all the options as default, **if the setup ask for the old password, it means it still finds the older datafiles somewhere**. So start all over again and try to find where the old data files are.

Other course of action is, during the installation, when asked about wich database to install, select the last option (I dont remember the name) for MyISAM. This will install in C:\ProgramData.... 
After this, go back to the item 1 (uninistall, erase, etc)

Hope this helps. I used `mysql-essential-5.1.46.-win32.msi` package, but I'm pretty sure its the same for the 64bit.

Regards
Alex