# Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed. On win 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I have had to reinstall MySQL, however the service is failing to start with the above cause listed in evnt viewer.

One [solution is apparently](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,144428,250105) to delete a couple of files prefixed with 'ib_logfile' which represent any old databases.  However I do not have these files, and my service is still failing to start ... ? When I say I don't have these files I did a search using the windows search with zero results, and they are definitely not present in my mysql install directory. And I don't have the "documents and setting/appilcation data' folder referenced in link.

In fact I only have only one mysql install directory, I know where that is - what do I need to delete/change ? The instance is configured OK, I ran that as administrator and it is listed in services, but the service itself fails to start

Any tips, other than going over to postgresql ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/143019/36032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked solution helped me, I had to change the my.ini file in install directory, specifically this property to point at the correct location :

```
datadir="F:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data"
```

Which I got about 10 sec's after positing question, hey ho, will leave it up for others.

Comment: NimChimpsky u rockkkkk... correct solution. Keep it up.
-Raj

Comment: @Raj lol, thanks. You could just vote up though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here's what I did to fix it:

1. Delete the following files:

   - C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\ib_logfile0
   - C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\ib_logfile1
2. Launch services.msc and start the MySQL55 service.